# What is broker neutral trading system?Can I use leverage if using broker neutral EMS?

Tags: trading, hedge-fund

What really means broker neutral trading system?Can I  use leverage if using broker neutral EMS?

Comment: Prime brokerage is what your looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_brokerage

Answer (score 2):

> What really means broker neutral trading system?

It means that you can have one piece of trading software that executes your trades and routes them to one or more brokers (with whom you have accounts, of course) for settlement.  You don't have to trade through your broker's high or low touch trading desks to execute and settle your trades with them.

> Can I use leverage if using broker neutral EMS?

Yes. When you use a broker neutral front end your orders will still run through the electronic order desk at your prime broker and will still be subject to the margin agreement and trading constraints that you have agreed to with them.  During the setup of your accounts with the software vendor and your prime broker(s), they will handle the back-end connections and configurations so that you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use leverage. Broker neutral means the trading system is provided by an independent vendor that will connect to any broker that you require. You are their client, and they are not affiliated or loyal to a specific broker.